# Rails 4 - How to render each version of a record with a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If you had a boilerplate scaffold for a rails model `document` you would get one model, controller, view and a bunch of other files that I'm going to ignore for the moment.

Over time new features are added to the application and the `document` model gets a few more fields.

In my application, I am trying to have documents such that once they are archived, the data never changes (that's easy to do), however the view used to render old archived documents has since changed and will display things that wenr;t there when the document was archived.

Is there a way to associate each `document` with a version of the/a view so that not only does the data remain the same, but the way it is rendered is also the same?

Comment: views are dynamically generated with the model you retrive from your db.. so if you add new fields..they'll appear on the old data as well.. you can either use a different template for your archived data viewing.. or just use if filters on your show template something like `unless document.archived?` to filter non-relevent fields for archived records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You could just add a `version` or `archive_version` column to that table, set all the existing ones as `view_version` 1, and render eg. `show_archived_v1.html.erb` from your controller for those records.

For "current" records, you can detect that the `archive_version` is blank and just render `show.html.erb`.

As you get a new type of version that needs to be archived, just store them with 2 in the `archive_version` column, and render `show_archived_v2.html.erb` wheb displaying them.

Comment: Or another option would be to store the template inside the Database. Obviously not ideal, but if we're talking about a small document with a small footprint, it would probably be a better idea rather than having n templates.